# Are there any equivalents of isfile() or isdir() in Django Template Language?

Tags: python, django

I want to achieve something like

```
{% for file in fileList %}
        {% if file isfile %}
             <a href="{% url 'GA:download' file %}">{{file}}</a><br>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

or should I just change the context I gave to the template?

My `views.py` looks like this

```
def index(request):
    fileList = os.listdir(settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    context = {'fileList':fileList}
    return render(request, 'gallery/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
{% for file in fileList %}
        {% if file.media %}
             <a href="{% url 'GA:download' file %}">{{file}}</a><br>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly last month, but now it doesn't work. Could you elaborate what `.media` is so I can fix this?